Gurobi does not find the nonzero optimum, despite there clearly is one?
I have this convex program that I am trying to solve - it works fine, but I cannot see why q[499] = -1900 (and rest are 0) is not a solution that maximizes the objective function? For q[499] = -1900, the corresponding xi_IB[499] = 500. So, if q[:] = 0, then the objective value is 2495. Whereas for q[499] = -1900 (and rest are 0) it is 2533, i.e. clearly larger.
I have checked the constraints:
q[499] = -1900 <= qnorm[499] and -q[499] = 1900 <= qnorm[499] implies qnorm[499] = 1900 (as qnorm >= 0).
1/n * gp.quicksum(qnorm[i] for i in N) = 1/500*1900 = 3.8 <= theta (=8), so clearly ok.
xi_IB[499] - q[499]/alpha = 500 - (-1900)/1 = 2400 <= 2400 (ok)
-(xi_IB[499] - q[499]/alpha) = -(500 - (-1900)/1) = -2400 <= 2400 (ok)
All constraints are satisfied?? What is going on? Do I miss something completely obvious?
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp

# Declare model
model = gp.Model("Revenue")
model.Params.LogToConsole = 0 # Suppress console output

# Decision variables (presolved)
x_L = 10
x_S = 0

# radius
theta = 8

xi_IB = np.arange(500)
n = len(xi_IB)
N = range(n)

# Dual variables from reformulation
qnorm = model.addVars(n, name="qnorm", vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)
q = model.addVars(n, name="q", vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

############################################
## Model Constraints
############################################

# constraints
alpha = 1
model.addConstrs(q[i] <= qnorm[i] for i in N)
model.addConstrs(-q[i] <= qnorm[i] for i in N)
model.addConstr(1/n*gp.quicksum(qnorm[i] for i in N) <= theta) # sum of abs(q[i])

# absolute value <= 2400
model.addConstrs(xi_IB[i] - q[i]/alpha <= 2400 for i in N)
model.addConstrs(-(xi_IB[i] - q[i]/alpha) <= 2400 for i in N)

obj_fn = 1/n*gp.quicksum(alpha*((xi_IB[i] - q[i]/alpha)*(x_L - x_S)) for i in N)

# Set Objective function
model.setObjective(obj_fn, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Optimize model
model.optimize()

print(f"Objective Value: {model.ObjVal}")

for i in N:
    if q[i].X > 1e-6 or q[i].X < -1e-6:  # Assuming a small threshold to determine non-zero values
        print("_____________________________")
        print(f"q[{i}] = {q[i].X}")
        print(f"xi_IB[{i}] = {xi_IB[i]}")


Try fixing the variable values to the solution you expect and see if it accepts it.  A wrong result is possible if the solver runs into numerical issues.  What do the coefficient ranges look like? (These appear in the log).

The lower bound in the addVars() call is zero by default. See the Gurobi documentation.

@Erwin Kalvelagen You should make that an answer, short but sweet. The key documentation is  addVars ( *indices, lb=0.0, ub=float('inf'), obj=0.0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="" )  at https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addvars.html

Great! Now it makes sense - thanks a lot :-)
